# How to calculate and show a sale value in a Django App/class?

Tags: python, django

I'm quite new to Django and I have to make this little program. It basically consists of two apps, (Sales and Registration). In the Registration app, there is a class called Product that has three attributes: Name, Price, and Quantity (in stock). In the Sales app, there is a class of the same name that has four attributes: date, product, quantity (quantity of the same product that I'm selling) and the seller (you can select one of the registered users).

What I have to do is show the total value of the sale as soon as you select the product and the quantity of that product that you are selling. (Price * Quantity). If it's not clear, I'm trying to 'sell' via this class in the sales app. Later on, I'll try to implement to reduce the quantity in stock and etc.

Unfortunately, I don't know how to do it. The total price can be shown after I click save, there's no problem with that.

I am mainly concerned if it's even possible to obtain what's selected in 'product' to obtain its 'Price", before clicking in the Save option.

## (registration app) models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Product(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    Quantity = models.IntegerField()
    Price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

## (sales app) models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models
from registration.models import Product    

class Sales(models.Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
    seller = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Sales"

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.product)
```

Comment: If you mean having an overview of the result without saving your object, you must implement an ajax view that do the job and returns as JsonResponse the  data you need and update your page via js.

Comment: Have you ever solved this? Casually I'm doing a pretty similar app and I'm stuck on the same thing.

Comment: I ended up creating a field called total price and then creating a new save function (overwriting the existing one). In this new save function i did the math and assigned it to that total price field, so when the user clicks save and goes back to the object or click save and continue editing, the total price shows up.